# Apex Trigger Avoid nested loop while inserting or updating record child-parent relationship

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class UpdateandInsertAccountRecordHandler {
    public static void onAfterInsert(List<Account> accList)
    {
        Set<Id> aNames = New Set<ID>();

        FOR(Account A : AccList)
        {
            IF(A.Ownerid != NULL)
            {
                aNames.Add(A.Ownerid);
            }
        }

        List<User> UserList = [Select Id, Name from USER where id in : aNames];


        FOR(Account A : AccList)
        {
            FOR(User U : UserList)
            {
                IF(a.ownerid == U.id)
                {
                    A.Sales_Rep__C = U.Name;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Force.com platform does allow you to instantiate a `Map<Id, sObject>` based on the `List<sObject>`, so **UserList** can be transformed to the following structure:

`Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([Select Id, Name from USER where id in : aNames]);`

Based on that, it is possible to retrieve a User by Id, so you may get rid of inner loop in second part of code.

```
for(Account a : AccList) {
    if(userMap.containsKey(a.ownerId)){
      A.Sales_Rep__C = userMap.get(a.ownerId).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much , you solved my problem